# Haven't been able to solve this:

Tags: sql, group-by, sum

Can't solve this and just haven't been able to wonder what's going wrong:

```
SELECT    
    CODE, NAME,
    BRANCH, SALESP,
    CASE 
        WHEN SUM(S1) = 0 THEN NULL
        ELSE SUM(S1) 
    END as S1,
    CASE 
       WHEN SUM(V1) = 0 THEN NULL
       ELSE SUM(V1) 
    END as V1,
    CASE 
       WHEN SUM(CHANGE) = 0 THEN NULL
       ELSE SUM(CHANGE) 
    END as CHANGE
FROM 
    SAESQL7_E03.[dbo].[p1]
WHERE   
    S1 <> 0 
    OR CHANGE <> 0
GROUP BY
    CODE, NAME, BRANCH, SALESP
```

Resulting in:

```
code  name    branch   salesp   s1   v1   change
-------------------------------------------------
1     Max     A        S        20   10    -5
2     Ben     A                 10    3     5
2     Ben     B                 20    5    10
```

The problem is in the 3rd column which is always wrong if a customer is in more than one branch.

(Max's example when customer only in one branch, always right; Ben's example case with two or more branches, first branch always right, following branches always wrong)

The table of origin has the correct data being:

```
   code  name    branch   salesp    S1  V1   V2   change
   ---------------------------------------------------
    1     Max     A        S        20   5   10    -5
    2     Ben     A                 10   8    3     5
    2     Ben     B                 20  10    5     5
```

`CHANGE` column comes from:

```
   SUM (V1-V2) AS CHANGE
```

Comment: You are using `S1` column in your query, but I don't see that column in your table of origin.

Comment: You say thing are wrong but dont explain why. Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The "3rd column" is "branch" in the table of origin and in the result, so what is wrong?  What is the **column name** that has a "wrong value" in it?

Comment: I corrected after your comments:

The problem is in the final Row

When there is a repeated customer (same code, name) but different branch

I get a wrong result (V2 value is ignored and taken as zero)

The corect result should be 5 not 10 (third row)

Comment: The Column name with wrong value is CHANGE

Comment: It's still entirely unclear what is wrong with the value `10` here. Please share what `SAESQL7_E03.[dbo].[p1]` looks like and what your desired results would be if your query were working as you want it to. What is this "Table of origin" that is "Correct". Why not just use that then... ? Why are you sharing that with us.

Comment: The title should actually describe the issue or question.

Comment: @csmckelvey -- yes, it's a terrible title. OP, your title could be used to describe essentially every post ever.  If you could solve it, you wouldn't have asked here.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, your query is correct and gives the correct answers!  Something is wrong; we'll try to find out what.  It looks like you're running on Microsoft SQL Server, so that is what I used for my tests.

Here is the origin table:

```
1> select * from p1;
2> go
code  name branch salesp   s1   v1   v2   change
----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ---- ---- --------
    1 Max  A      S        20    5   10       -5
    2 Ben  A      NULL     10    8    3        5
    2 Ben  B      NULL     20   10    5        5

(3 rows affected)
```

Here is your query:

```
1> SELECT
2>     CODE, NAME,
3>     BRANCH, SALESP,
4>     CASE
5>         WHEN SUM(S1) = 0 THEN NULL
6>         ELSE SUM(S1)
7>     END as S1,
8>     CASE
9>        WHEN SUM(V1) = 0 THEN NULL
10>        ELSE SUM(V1)
11>     END as V1,
12>     CASE
13>        WHEN SUM(CHANGE) = 0 THEN NULL
14>        ELSE SUM(CHANGE)
15>     END as CHANGE
16> FROM
17>     p1
18> WHERE
19>     S1 <> 0
20>     OR CHANGE <> 0
21> GROUP BY
22>     CODE, NAME, BRANCH, SALESP
23> ;
24> go
```

... and the results:

```
  CODE NAME BRANCH SALESP    S1   V1   CHANGE
------ ---- ------ ------ ----- ---- --------
     1 Max  A      S         20    5       -5
     2 Ben  A      NULL      10    8        5
     2 Ben  B      NULL      20   10        5

(3 rows affected)
```

So something is wrong.  Could you try doing a select from the origin table again, please?  Does it contain any other data?  If not, then 
    select * from SAESQL7_E03.[dbo].[p1]
would be best.

If there is a lot more data, do this to make sure you include the same rows as used in the query above:

```
select    
    code,
    name,
    branch,
    salesp,
    s1,
    v1,
    v2,
    change
from 
    SAESQL7_E03.dbo.p1
where   
    s1 <> 0 
    or change <> 0;
```

V1 in the query seems to return the values from v2 in the source.  Is that a clue?  Although you are aggregating, there is never more than one value in each group in the source data.  Is this just a test with 1 row per group, with the intention to increase the number of rows per group?